# where can i download a pretrained word2vec map?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I have been learning about NLP models and came across word embedding, and saw the examples in which it is possible to see relations between words by calculating their dot products and such.

What I am looking for is just a dictionary, mapping words to their representative vectors, so I can play around with it. I know that I can build a model and train it and create my own map but I just want the already trained map as a python variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answerer and the commentators, I finally found exactly what I was looking for here:
https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/materials/Gensim%20word%20vector%20visualization.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try out Google's [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) model trained with about 100 billion words from various news articles.

An interesting fact about word vectors, `w2v(king) - w2v(man) + w2v(woman) ≈ w2v(queen)`

Comment: And you can specifically load that file with library like `gensim` that supports word-vectors, using its `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` method: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html – the `KeyedVectors` object will behave like a Python `dict`, though it's not literally a `dict` for performance reasons.

Comment: If that `GoogleNews` set of 3 million words/short-phrases is too large to be convenient to work with – as it takes ~3+GB of RAM to load, and more GB to do `most_similar()` operations – you can load a subset using the `limit` parameter. EG: `goog_wordvecs = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(' GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True, limit=100000)` to load just the 1st 100,000 words – less than 4% of all its words, but still enough to cover most common words.